# In Lucy, is CPH4 based on something in real-life?

Tags: realism, lucy

[Lucy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucy_(2014_film)) features CPH4, a drug that enhances physical and mental capabilities. Is this drug/molecule based on a real-life substance? Multiple real-life substances? Looking for in-universe or official explanations.

Answer (score 4):

[Nootropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nootropic) drugs have been around for quite a while. And there are [products](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/a-safe-drug-to-boost-brainpower) and research going on in this field.

Also [CPH4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6-carboxytetrahydropterin_synthase) is real. But it does not work as shown in Lucy.

[Check this answer on Biology SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22785/is-cph4-from-science-fiction-movie-lucy-real)

Comment: NZT kinda work that way though